# Merge layers with different geometry

Tags: qgis

I need to merge two different layers but they don't have the same geometry, in particular one contains points and one is a polygon (province). Is it possible to do so by converting them to the same geometry and what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't merge the two different geometry types into typical GIS file.

I think what you're looking for is "Join Attributes by Location." That will join the attributes of the point file into those of the polygon file, based on spatial intersection.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a provincial centroid wont cut it, I would just buffer the points to an appropriate distance for your purpose and use those polygons to merge with the provincial boundary.

Comment: Thank you for response, the problem is that buffers around the points don't have in the attribute table the original data of the points, in fact it is empty. I need to keep them in order to count the elements after merging.

Comment: I see, there is likely a more direct route but could you use a join from the points to the buffer and then merge?