# QGIS 3.10 problem with merging layers & multipart promotion

Tags: qgis

I would like to merge a few layers in QGIS. However, I can't do this.
When I run the MMGIS option, then I am getting:

**Merged input_layers must all be same type of geometry (MultiLineString != Polygon)**

According to the MMQGIS author, all layers must be in the same geometry.

In this case, I set all the same geometries for my objects:

[image]

But it didn't solve my problem:

[image]

So I tried another way:

In the Vector - Data Management Tools - Merge Vector Layers  I selected my layers. Unfortunately, I got sth like this:

[image]

According to this question:

[Merge layers with different geometry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190596/merge-layers-with-different-geometry/190599)

I used "Join attributes by location" option, although afterward, I got only 1 layer, even when I select "Create the separate features for joint..."

[image]

Should I use the GRASS as per below?

[Error in merging two shapefiles of different geometry types](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163820/error-in-merging-two-shapefiles-of-different-geometry-types)

I would like to have all the layers in the picture below merged:

[image]

Or should I maybe do sth like this:

[Merging layers into one- QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307896/merging-layers-into-one-qgis)

**UPDATE:**

As per the advice below I tried the "Promote to the multipart" option.~
Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my query too, since this tool can promote only 1 layer:

[image]

In the effect I have only 1 layer "multipart", but how about other ones?

[image]

Comment: You could try using the `Promote to multipart` tool on all your layers before merging to ensure they have the same geometry type.

Comment: Where can I find it?
I just found the repository with no examples really:

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/es/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#promote-to-multipart

Comment: From the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: A yeah, here we go! Thank you! I haven't taken the processing toolbox into account at that moment.

Comment: Since the "Promote to the multipart" options offer only 1 layer "promotion" I had to updated my query.

Comment: What I meant was to use the `Promote to multipart` on **all** of the layers you are interested in. Then when you have all the outputs, run the merge tool. If you don't want to use the `Promote to multipart` each time for each layer, run it as a **batch process** by right-clicking it from the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: I did it and I am still getting error:
All layers must have same geometry type! Encountered a Line layer when expecting a Polygon layer.

Comment: You can only merge multipart polygon shapefiles together, you can't mix with multipart lines or multipart points (if that is what you were trying to do?).

Comment: So how about the lines then? Is it possible to do?

Comment: If you want to store your shapefiles into a single file, consider the [GeoPackage layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174953/how-to-add-another-layer-to-geopackage-in-qgis). This will let you store polygons, lines, points etc in a single file.

Comment: I tried it. It would be helpful, but I can't import it straight to QGIS and save as a shapefile.